# Once again, another Linux movie quote!

Tags: knowledge, rebus, computer-puzzle

Because I can't get off this linux movie quote train, here is another one! Can you find the famous movie quote hidden in this linux block?

```
root:/# rm /i
root:/# echo "30 13 * * * /bin/bash -c 'if [ ! -f /i ]; then touch /i; fi'" | crontab -
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's

> I'll be back

from the movie

> [The Terminator](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247)

Since the script

> removes the file named "i", but also ensures that it will be created again at 13.30

Comment: Good one. I was totally hung up on the actual time in the cron job.

Comment: You're right! Nice job!